# Problems with paragraphs

Tags: paragraphs, paraphrasing

Problems with correct sentences

> I would like to study related algebraic problems in the complexity framework,one of the challenge in this would be to find suitable parameter for these problems.

```
                                    OR
```

> I would like to study related algebraic problems in the complexity framework. One of the challenge in this would be to find suitable parameter for these problems.

Question : Which one is more correct?

Comment: (1) Please ask only one question at a time, not three unrelated questions. (2) Please make sure that before you ask here, you’ve tried to find answers on your own by looking in, for example, dictionaries, grammar books, style guides, etc., and make sure to include in your question what these sources told you and why that didn’t answer your question. (3) Why are you using a comma to separate two entirely independent sentences in the first example?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

They are two sentences, so the second version is better. But it is not good English unless you make challenge a plural: challenges.